# oracle: how to get unique values by group?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I have a database table like the following:

```
date col
1    A
1    A
1    B
2    C
```

I would like to get the unique values of `col` for each `date`. So as output I am looking for:

```
date col
1    A
1    B
2    C
```

I tried the following without success:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE, COL
FROM MYDATA
GROUP BY DATE
```

But I am getting :

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

What is the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: You could `group by date, col`

Comment: or change `Group By` to `Order By`

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`! No need to do GROUP BY since no aggregate functions are involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`. Use either one or the other.

Both below queries will produce the expected result.

Option 1 :

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE, COL FROM MYDATA
```

Option 2 :

```
SELECT DATE, COL FROM MYDATA GROUP BY DATE, COL
```

Comment: thanks. i realize I still think in terms of pandas stuff... like df.groupby().unique().. btw is there a good online SQL server where we can play with queries?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ : these are called **fiddles**, and there are several of them, depending on which RDBMS you want to play around with (not all fiddles support all DB servers) : http://sqlfiddle.com/, https://www.db-fiddle.com/, https://dbfiddle.uk/, ...